# showing a collection of sets contain all closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be infinite set and $a \in X $. Let $$\mathscr{F} = \{ A \subset X: |A| \; \; finite \; \;, a \notin A \}$$

Then $\mathscr{F}$ is the set all of all closed sets for some topology $\mathcal{T} $ on $X$. Also, any two continuous maps $f,g: (X, \mathscr{T}) \to Y$ ( $Y$ is metric space) have the property that if $f(b) = g(b)$ for all $b \neq a $, then $f(a) = g(a)$.

In my notes my professor posted this theorem without proof, so I was wondering what is best way to proof this theorem.

Comment: HINT: Consider $h: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h(x) = d_Y(f(x), g(x))$. This is continuous and vanishes on the whole $X \setminus \{a \}$. What can you say about $h^{-1}(0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathscr{F}$ actually isn’t the set of all closed sets for a topology on $X$, but $\mathscr{F}\cup\{X\}$ is. The open sets are $\varnothing$ and all sets $U$ such that $a\in U$ and $X\setminus U$ is finite. (This topology is the intersection of the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) and the [particular point topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology) having $a$ as the particular point.) Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the collection of such sets; it’s straightforward to check that $\varnothing,X\in\mathscr{T}$ and that $\mathscr{T}$ is closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions and therefore is a topology on $X$.

Now suppose that $f,g:X\to Y$ are continuous and are such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X\setminus\{a\}$, and suppose that $f(a)\ne g(a)$. Then there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ such that $f(a)\in U$, $g(a)\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. (Why?) Consider $f^{-1}[U]$ and $g^{-1}[V]$ to derive a contradiction; you’ll use the continuity of $f$ and $g$ and the fact that $X$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The topology $\mathcal{T} $ on $X$ is defined in the obvious way:

$\mathcal{T} = \{ A \subset X: A \text{ is infinite}, a\in A \}\cup \{\emptyset\} $, [check that this is a topology, and $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all closed sets (apart from $X$)]

For the second part, we have $f-g$ is continuous. As {0} is closed in $Y$, $(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed in $X$. But $X\setminus \{a\} \subset (f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$, the former being infinite. From the first part we conclude that $(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$ must be the whole set $X$, so contains $a$.